# How I can build react application to one bundle .js based on react-scripts library?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

kindly we need to build my created app with static bundle how I can do it with the react-react-app template.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build) it will be sufficient to run

```
npm run build
```

if you've created your react app using `create-react-app`.

I have not checked it.

A second way would be to use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) as a third party tool.